# WP - Advanced custom field date display

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to extract a date from WP advanced custom field (ver. 4.x).

By default when I just want to display a date, it displays a date in the following format:

```
<?php the_field('event_date'); ?>
```

03051998

I'm trying to do the following:

```
<?php
    $event_d = new DateTime();
    $event_month = $event_d->format('M');
    $event_day = $event_d->format('d');
    $event_year = $event_d->format('Y');                                
?>

<div class="row border-bottom mb-1">   
       <div class="col-md-2 bg-light d-flex">  
       <div class="text-center">
            <h3><?php echo $event_day; ?></h3>
            <h3><?php echo $event_month; ?></h3>
            <h3><?php echo $event_year; ?></h3> 

        </div>
 </div>
```

The above works fine displaying today's date. However, when I add the date to a new instance of date object, the page does not display at all.

```
$event_d = new DateTime(get_field('event_date'));
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** In `DateTime()`, you should pass acceptable format such as 'YYYY-MM-DD' (you can read more here - http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). Change the **Save format** of your ACF date field to 'yy-mm-dd', update your post and try again.

**Solution 2:** Manipulate your ACF date field to 'YYYY-MM-DD' before passing to `DateTime()` function.